# How to link against lOpenGL32 using Visual Studio and Qt Add-in?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, visual-c++, linker-errors

I use Visual Studio 2019 and the QT add-in. There I have LNK2019 errors about OpenGL methods. My guess was that I would have to link against lOpenGL32, but I don't know how.

Comment: Please add at least some of these error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I used this header

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\gl\GL.h
```

instead of the QOpenGLFunctions class.